# Magento2 performance testing error

Tags: magento2, performance, testing

When I run the first time:

```
magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
```

I got this error:

```
Generating simple products... Error in data structure: entity values are mixed
```

Now I run it again and get this error:

```
Generating categories... URL key for specified store already exists.
```

Is there something that I should delete before running it again? I can't see anything here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html